# TeamCitySharper get changesets from builds

Tags: c#

I am using TeamCitySharper to get information about builds and changesets.
I've used `AllSinceDate` to get builds:

```
 var buildsDiagnostics = client.Builds.AllSinceDate(new DateTime(2015, 08, 30));
```

[image]

However, Changes property is always null and I can not connect between builds and related change sets. Wheareas,`Changes.All()` returns empty `Files` property:

```
var changesAll = client.Changes.All();
```

[image]

What I have done wrong or how how can I get all change sets related to particular build?

Comment: Do you try List<Change> ByBuildConfigId(string buildConfigId)?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it too.
It is looks like a bug in TeamCitySharper.